# Couchbase get Operation timeout randomly

Tags: couchbase

Environment:

Couchbase server 3.1
Client SDK 2.1.4

I have a code that wrapped the get value operation from couchbase. And when it is running, randomly throw TimeOutException error.

No luck after dig from CB's forum and docs.

Appreciate if any clue.

The error screenshot is as below:

[image: TimeOutException]

And my code is as below :

```
package com.fairyland.jdp.framework.service;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket;
import com.couchbase.client.java.Cluster;
import com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster;
import com.couchbase.client.java.document.JsonDocument;
import com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject;
import com.couchbase.client.java.env.DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment;
import com.fairyland.jdp.framework.util.PropsUtil;

public class CouchbaseService implements ServletContextListener{
         private static Cluster cluster;
         private static Bucket ticketBucket;
//      private CouchbaseService(){
//              
//      }
         public static void init(){
                   if(ticketBucket == null){
                            String[] hostnames = PropsUtil.get("couchbaseAddr").split(",");
                            cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment
                                .builder()
                                .build(),hostnames);
                            String pwd = PropsUtil.get("couchbasePwd");
                            if(StringUtils.isEmpty(pwd)){
                                     ticketBucket = cluster.openBucket(PropsUtil.get("bucketName"),60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                            }else{
                                     ticketBucket = cluster.openBucket(PropsUtil.get("bucketName"),pwd,60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                            }

                   }
         }
         private static synchronized Bucket getBucket(){
                   init();
         return ticketBucket;
         }
         public static void close(){
                   if(cluster!=null){
                            cluster.disconnect();
                   }
         }
         public static boolean setValue(String key,int timeout,Serializable value){
         String valueJson = null;
         try {
//               valueJson = JacksonUtil.getInstance().bean2Json(value);
                   valueJson = serialize(value);
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                   }
//      String expireTime = sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+getTimeout(value)));
//      String ticketType = getTicketType(value);
         // Create a user and insert it
         JsonObject json = JsonObject.empty()
            .put("value", valueJson);
//                   .put("expireTime",expireTime)
//                         .put("ticketType",ticketType);
         JsonDocument doc = null;
         if(timeout<=0)
                   doc = JsonDocument.create(key, json);
         else
                   doc = JsonDocument.create(key,timeout, json);
         getBucket().upsert(doc, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         JsonDocument result = getBucket().upsert(doc);
         if(result!=null && result.content().getString("value")!=null){
                   return true;
         }else{
                   return false;
         }
    }
         public static Object getValue(String key){
                   JsonDocument doc = null;
                   doc = getBucket().get(key);
                   if(doc==null)
                            return null;
         String valueJson = doc.content().getString("value");
         Object value = null;
                   value = deSerialize(valueJson);
         return value;
         }
         public static JsonDocument removeValue(String key){
                   return getBucket().remove(key);
         }
    public static String serialize(Serializable obj){
         try {
                   ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream); 
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(obj);   
            String serStr = byteArrayOutputStream.toString("ISO-8859-1"); 
            serStr = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(serStr, "UTF-8"); 
            objectOutputStream.close(); 
            byteArrayOutputStream.close();
            return serStr;
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                   }
         return null;
    }
    public static Object deSerialize(String value){
         try {
                   String redStr = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(value, "UTF-8"); 
            ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(redStr.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")); 
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);  
            Object obj = objectInputStream.readObject();  
            objectInputStream.close(); 
            byteArrayInputStream.close(); 
            return obj;
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                   }
         return null;
    }
         @Override
         public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
                   close();
         }
         @Override
         public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
                   init();
         }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a cluster? are all nodes up? anything in the couchbase log? perhaps you can try to recreate this using a different couchbase client (to rule out a problem in the couchbase client).

Comment: It's a cluster with 3 nodes up. From the admin console all nodes are running without warning or error. Recreate a different cb client is a good idea to have a try.